# npm install with a docker-compose project

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I have a dockerized project that has three apps and three databases. The three apps are written in node and use `npm` as usual.

I have a script that clones the three repos, `docker-compose.yaml` mounts the three containers and uses a `Dockerfile` for each of the three projects to basically just do an `npm install` and run them.

This is all working fine, but the whole point of this exercise is to make the cluster of projects easy to set up and run for the purposes of development. Actually working on the project code is not a problem since it gets cloned by the developer, but `npm install` is done through docker and thus root. This means that `node_modules` in the repos is owned by root.

A developer cannot simply do `npm install` to add a new package to the repo because they won't have permissions on `node_modules` and the module would possibly be built with a different architecture depending on their host system.

I have thought about creating a script that runs `npm install` in the container instead, but this has a couple of caveats:

1. `root` would own `package.json`
2. This breaks a typical node developer's flow ... they are used to just doing `npm install`

Like I said above, the whole point of this is to make it as easy to jump in and develop as possible, so I want to get as close to a common development experience as I can.

Are there any suggestions for handling installation of node modules in a docker container for development of a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common problem with mounted source folders, the best solution I have come up with so far is to simply match the `uid/gid` of the host user to some fixed user in the container. Until recently one had to resort to some external tools and dockerfile/compose templating, with the latest docker-compose versions *(>=1.6.0)* you can do the following now:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
ARG HOST_UID=1000
RUN adduser -D -H -u ${HOST_UID} -s /bin/sh npm
USER npm
RUN echo "i'm $(whoami) and have uid: ${HOST_UID}"
```

Notice the [ARG](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) directive. The value of `HOST_UID` is passed at runtime via `docker build --build-arg HOST_UID=${UID}`. Then just add a custom `npm` user with the value of `HOST_UID` as its `uid` and set it as default [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) for all following commands.

`--build-arg` is now also supported by docker-compose and the new version 2 yml format:

```
version: '2'
services:
  foo:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        HOST_UID: ${UID}
```

Provided `UID` is set on your host, `docker-compose up foo` will build the image with a default user that matches your `uid` on the host. The important lesson I learned there was that the `uid/gid` is all that matters for permissions, the actual user/group names are irrelevant.

Another technique I used a few times is to replace the `uid` of a fixed user in `/etc/passwd/` via sed on container start, if a certain env is set. This avoids image rebuilds and is suitable for images that are expected to run straight from some repository.

Lastly I would recommend to fully embrace the docker philosophy, meaning your devs should only use the project containers for tasks like `npm install`. You avoid the inevitable version mismatch and other headaches down the road.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but just a couple followups. Is `1000` going to be the UID I want to use every time? Could you also elaborate on your last paragraph a bit more. What version mismatch headaches are you referring to? Also they would be editing and working with the code on their host machine, not in the container (though as long as I could document how I begrudgingly accept doing `npm install` through the container)

Comment: `1000` in this case is just a provided default value, else `--build-arg HOST_UID=` becomes a requirement to even start the build. By version mismatch I was refering to the tools on the devs host and inside the container. Using the IDE of your host is fine.